# How to calculate free available time from the json output?

Tags: javascript

I have this kind of json with start and end time properties in the objects.

```
var meetings = [
  {
    id: '1',
    start_time: "2020-11-15T08:30:00+00:00",
    end_time: "2020-11-15T14:15:00+00:00"
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    start_time: "2020-11-15T19:30:00+00:00",
    end_time: "2020-11-15T20:30:00+00:00"
  },
];
```

So two meetings first one: 08:30 - 14:15 second: 19:30-20:30

There are 24 availavable hours for working so:

```
start_time = '00:00:00';
end_time = '23:59:00';
```

but in the format that i need would be

```
var start_time = '2020-11-15T00:00:00+00:00';
var end_time = '2020-11-15T23:59:00+00:00';
```

How can i calculate the avalavable hours depening on the already maked  meetings?
So because the first meeting is from 08:30 - 14:15 and the second 19:30-20:30 i will need json with the following result with the available hours:

```
[
  {
    start_time:'2020-11-15T00:00:00+00:00',
    end_time:'2020-11-15T08:30:00+00:00'
  },

  {
    start_time:'2020-11-15T14:15:00+00:00',
    end_time:'2020-11-15T19:30:00+00:00'
  },

  {
    start_time:'2020-11-15T20:30:00+00:00',
    end_time:'2020-11-15T23:59:00+00:00'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var meetings = [
  {
    id: '1',
    start_time: "2020-11-15T08:30:00+00:00",
    end_time: "2020-11-15T14:15:00+00:00"
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    start_time: "2020-11-15T19:30:00+00:00",
    end_time: "2020-11-15T20:30:00+00:00"
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    start_time: "2020-11-15T20:50:00+00:00",
    end_time: "2020-11-15T21:30:00+00:00"
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    start_time: "2020-11-15T22:30:00+00:00",
    end_time: "2020-11-15T22:40:00+00:00"
  },

];

var startTime = '2020-11-15T00:00:00+00:00';
var endTime = '2020-11-15T23:59:00+00:00';



let availableHours = [];

for(let index in meetings){
    if(index != meetings.length - 1){
        index == 0 ? availableHours.push({start_time: startTime, end_time: meetings[index]['start_time'] }) : 0;
        availableHours.push({start_time: meetings[index].end_time, end_time: meetings[+index + 1]['start_time'] });
    } else {
        availableHours.push({start_time: meetings[index].end_time, end_time: endTime })
    }    
}

console.log(meetings)
console.log(availableHours)
```

Comment: THANKS for your response.But the hours from 14:15 until 19:30 are not included.Can you please provide new code example with that case also, for all hours

Comment: code updated, it's done. good luck with your project!